# Connection between model, view and controller

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I've searched a lot and read a lot about the concept of MVC. But I still don't know how to connect them together. Suppose I have a controller class, view class and model class. If user did something in that view, view should notify controller the action and controller may need to communicate with model to get some data.

1. Now, does view hold a reference to the controller? Does the controller has a property of that model? Or they just using like "include"?
2. The data is saved in memory, or database? Memory means stored in variables.
3. More complicated case, one action from user may need many controllers and models involved. How to co-ordinate them together?

What I've done before is I create a "view controller", which has view and some actions of that view. 
And sometimes there is no model. All data is passed by parameter. If there are some models, some of them are singleton so I can get it everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very generic answer, depending on your system these can vary:

1. The `Controller` has a reference to the `View`, an `IBOutlet` for example. The View is not aware of the Controller, it's a dumb thing that receives info and displays it, that's it.
2. Depends on what you have in place, sometimes you don't need to persist the data and being on variables is enough. For persisting data, you have CoreData, plists or save them on the sandbox.
3. Normally you could have a parent Controller, holding references to child Controllers. Each child should be independent and the parent would be the "glue" between them.

I can point you to this repo I created, called [iOS Architecture](https://github.com/RuiAAPeres/iOSArchitecture), to help you understand how the controller and the model interact.

Comment: Much clear. And model should be independent that it has its own methods handling data right? Controller is handling actions from users (views). The relationship is many to many instead of one to one. For example, I have a PersonView show information about a person. PersonController handle actions from PersonView, but some actions may related to others so PersonController may need to invoke methods in ServerController. And PersonController may need to update PersonModel as well as other model like PeopleModel.

Comment: Model should be independent from the controller. The controller will typically handle actions performed on the `UIViews`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more points:

1. When your Action returns a View("SomeView"), it will check first if you have a layout, if not it will look for SomeView.cshtml in the Views folder of that controller.
2. If you want SomeView to talk to any Action in the controller, what you can do is to do a FormMethod.Post and assign the correct model and of course the Action name.  That action name should be decorated with [HttpPost] or you can do a FormMethod.Get and decorate it with [HttpGet] or just leave it blank since [HttpGet] is default.
3. If you want another action redirecting first to another action without going to a page, you use RedirectToAction() instead of View and change the type to ActionResult instead of ViewResult

I hope it makes sense to you :)